# White screen when embedding YouTube in iOS 7 web view

Tags: ios, ios7, youtube

I've been having issues with embedding a Youtube video into my app on iOS 7. It seems I'm not alone. Issue is when you embed using what almost every tutorial I have found suggests, all I end up with is a white box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but at least it works.

Find your youTube video, click Embed and tick 'Use old embed code'

Copy the 'value', including 'version'

eg. www.youtube.com/v/kjshdfksa=en_GB&version=3

Copy the code below into viewDidLoad and change the variables to your own

```
NSString *youTubeLink = @"www.youtube.com/v/kjshdfksa?hl=en_GB&amp;version=3";

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 260\"/></head><body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"260\" height=\"135\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://%@\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"http://%@\"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"260\" height=\"135\"></embed></object></div></body></html>", youTubeLink, youTubeLink];

youTubeWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
youTubeWebView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
[youTubeWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

This assumes you have a web view on your page, with a width of 260 and height of 135.